# How can I variably name an array in ruby and use it in java to show markers in google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, google-maps

Hi I am really new to ruby on rails and I stuck on a problem for days. I want to show multiple markers on google maps. Therefore an array with the location is created and the array should be filled by data from the ruby database.
It would be nice to have something like

my_array [n]

I have 160 markers and do not want to make 160 if cases and 160 entries in the javascript location array

Is there a way to create it automatically depending on n or something else?

```
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<%
160.times do |n|
 n += 1
 puts n.to_s
end


if  n = 1
my_array =  [PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).latitude, PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).longitude]  end %>
<% if  n = 2
my_array2 = [PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).latitude, PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).longitude] %>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [ new Array(<%=my_array.map(&:to_s).join(", ") end%>),
                  new Array(<%=my_array2.map(&:to_s).join(", ") end%>)];                    

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3759189132837, 9.741383492946625),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
 </script>
 </body>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [];

<% (1..160).each do |n| %>
  locations.push([<%=PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).latitude%>, <%=PotStandorte.find_by_id(n).longitude%>)])
<% end %>
```

I don't really know if that's what you are looking for but `new Array(xxx)` in javascript initializes an array with xxx elements (meaning xxx is size).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked!!!
I feel a bit stupid now since it is so easy... but I never tried it this way....